# How do I push an element to the end of it's container in CSS Layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to create a header with CSS Layout and I'm unable to place my 'contact' element to the far right of it's container 'main-nav'. I've tried the following in the html and css codes, but the "contacts" element remains where  the other elements in the 'main-nav' container are located. Please help!
PS: I'm new to development. I hope I can explain my troubles well enough. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MY WEB LAYOUT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="zone green">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
            <li class="push"><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="zone red">Cover</div>
    <div class="zone blue">Project Grid</div>
    <div class="zone yellow">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/* CSS */

```
body {
    margin: auto 0;
}

.zone {
    /*padding: 30px 50px;
    margin: 40px 60px;*/
    cursor:pointer;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    color: #FFF;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.zone:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    -o-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0px 5px 15px, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px -10px 20px;
}

/* NAV */
.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin: 0;
}

.contacts {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
}

.push {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-left: auto;
}

li {
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    color: #f5f5f6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- We put Display flex for the container not the child.

Change your nav section code with the following:

```html
 <nav class="zone green">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a href="">Contacts</a></li>
  </nav>
```

Then add the following css:

```css
 .zone{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;  
    }
```

The result (Run Code To See Result):

```css
 .zone{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;  
    }
```

```html
 <nav class="zone green">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a href="">Contacts</a></li>
    </nav>
```

At this point you just need to add the rest of the style.

Comment: Thank you. Although the code example you showed to me made the Contacts to appear on a different row instead; it did give me an insight on what to do. My code has run effectively now.

Answer (score 0):

Assign position :relative ; to #mainnav
And add right to contacts  e. g right:-20px or20px;try this in css.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Couldn't run your advice as I haven't got an #Id property in my html. Thanks anyways, my code has run effectively. I put display: flex; in the container before the .push child in my CSS and it worked eventually. Many thanks. PS: I also wrote off the .contacts element code in my CSS as it was ineffective since I only wrote a .push property in my html.